# HTML/CSS list image/bullet above/below

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS containing a list and its alignment. I managed to get the list elements at each corner of the div, now I want to try to get the image (that is basically used as the 'list-dot') to the top and bottom, so the top elements have their image centered above them and the bottom elements centered below them. 
Can someone help me here?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: beige;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.list-div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 75%;
}

.list-div li {
  position: absolute;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2){
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=B);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(3){
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=C);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(4){
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=D);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}



@media max-width:768px{
  
  
  .list-div li.animate{
  visibility: visible;
}
  .list-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content" id="list-cont">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul>
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Short picutre to clarifiy:
[image]

Comment: What you want? not able to understand

Comment: normally, the bullet of the list is on the left. Now I replaced the bullet with a background and I want to have the bullet above the list. I will add a little picture right now. Added picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: beige;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.list-div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 75%;
}

.list-div li {
  position: absolute;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
      list-style-type: none;
   
   padding-top: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    width:100px;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2){
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=B);
     list-style-type: none;
   
   padding-top: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    width:100px;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(3){
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=C);
    list-style-type: none;
   
   padding-bottom: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 100%;
    width:100px;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(4){
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=D);
    list-style-type: none;
   
   padding-bottom: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 100%;
    width:100px;
}



@media max-width:768px{
  
  
  .list-div li.animate{
  visibility: visible;
}
  .list-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content" id="list-cont">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul>
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats what I was looking for, thanks a lot. Didnt even thought of just trying postion-x :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `background-position` of list like below:-

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: beige;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.list-div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-div li {
  position: absolute;
}

.list-div li:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 41px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 55px 2px;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(2){
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=B);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 41px 10px 10px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 55px 2px;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(3){
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=C);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 42px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50px 54px;
}
.list-div li:nth-child(4){
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=D);
      list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 42px 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50px 54px;
}



@media max-width:768px{
  
  
  .list-div li.animate{
  visibility: visible;
}
  .list-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="half-width">
        <div class="half-width-content" id="list-cont">
          <div class="list-div">
            <ul>
              <li>Entry <br>A</li>
              <li>Entry <br>B</li>
              <li>Entry <br>C</li>
              <li>Entry <br>D</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: he wants the bottom row "bullets" to be positioned under the text

Comment: thanks,but I prefer @pencil a's solution, cause he used a percentage for the positon, thanks though!:)

Comment: Welcome @ItFreak

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your code now is displaying inline (bullet - Name - Letter).
And you want it one over the other.

So a quick idea is.

Create a Div. With 3 li inside. And add the bullet as an image or icon (themify icons for example)

```
<div> 
<li>image dot</li>
<li> Text </li>
<li> text </li>
</div
```

Hope was this your need.
You can keep the css, should work

Thanks

Comment: that was a approach from mine, but I searched for a clean solution with background-position. upvote though:)

Comment: yea, works like charm, but I will use the accepted answer, because a simple <li> with a CSS styled alignment seems 'cleaner' for me:)